# Parcel outputs "cannot resolve dependency" when building react widget

Tags: reactjs, widget, parceljs, react-widgets

So I am trying to build a react widget. I have completed the app and it's works fine as a react app, but when I try to build it with parcel as a widget so I can be able to embed it in any website, this is what I get when I run the widget build command.

> parcel build src/index.tsx --no-source-maps -d widget && cp build/static/css/*.css widget/index.css

> C:\Users\Genral Walker\Desktop\Coding\my-personal-works\PneumaCareHQ\consult-widgets\src\App.tsx:17:28: Cannot resolve dependency 'layouts/DashboardLayout'

This is my script package json

```
"scripts": {
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "build:widget": "parcel build src/index.tsx --no-source-maps -d widget && cp build/static/css/*.css widget/index.css"
  },
```

[image]

Comment: The error you're getting seems to indicate that there is an import statement in `src/App.ts` that tries to reference a file called `src/componentLoadingSpin`, but it doesn't exist, and that can't be found. Can you provide a complete, simplified repro - including the files that get built and the things they reference?

Comment: Also, you usually need to use `./component/LoadingSpin`. Currently it tries to load an npm package called "component"

Comment: Thanks Andrew, mischinc is right, parcel doesn't recognize if it's a component or a module. I change that and added the "./" to it.     The issue I have now is that it recognises another similar error-which I also changed.  And it keeps on moving to the next component...  Please is there a way I can set this so parcel can build the project without me manually editing all the import instances. I've got like 2000 of those. Thanks.

Comment: You could try to use [package aliases](https://parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#package-aliases) to re-direct what parcel thinks is a package called `component` (in node_modules) to a folder in your project (e.g. src/component)

Comment: Alright @AndrewStegmaier, I didn't know of this till now, looking into this right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright with the help from [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4739687/andrew-stegmaier), I was able to use package [package aliases](https://parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#package-aliases) to resolve the issue.

I inserted the components that were being resolved as modules in the package.json alias block to prevent that.

A simple example: if you have a component you want to import with absolute import method as such `import ComponentName from 'component/RouteComposer';` . In order to avoid running into an error when building, insert this in the alias block in package.json as so `"component*": "./src/component/",`.